# Visual representation of the fact that there are more irrational than rational numbers.

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, visualization

Would anybody know of a visual or even (preferably) geometric representation of this?

To make it more specific: Text, symbols and written numbers are predominantly used as labels, and and less to represent the (ir)rationals themselves, or relations between the two groups. Like, if you need an image or a picture for your answer, that's probably it.

For example:

[image]

It does not have to be a rigorous proof, just a visual approach—if possible.

At the same time, a (somewhat elementary) explanation of why it does not make sense to try to visualize this relation (geometrically) is just as welcome.

Comment: It definitely falls short of being a convincing argument, but looking at [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) is at least moderately enlightening; I can see the rationals are all separated out, then a whole line of irrationals piled at the bottom!

Comment: @MiloBrandt It becomes convincing after an infinite amount of time spent zooming in.

Comment: Why do you even need a visual representation that will most definitely fail to be a rigorous proof?

Comment: @KarloGrba alright. But in my opinion you can't expect to find even a visual one. Because our sense is too weak to discern different infinite cardinals. (Clear as Marty Cohen's answer may look, we can't really tell from it that the rationals are strictly fewer than the reals. For instance, the  natural numbers seemingly form a very sparse subset of the rationals on the real line, but the two sets are indeed of the same "size"/cardinal.)

Comment: @Vim Whatever the answer may be, I have to ask to find out.

Comment: @KarloGrba that's of course absolutely fine. But, just in my opinion, the reality might let you down this time because you can't always expect *intuition* to inspire *proof*. By the way, I find you accepted an answer using Lebesgue measure and claiming to be rigorous, but I don't think it can qualify as a real proof. See my comment below, if you are interested.

Comment: This is arguably the most counterintuitive fact in all of mathematics when historical significance is taken into account. It's arguably *the* theorem that demonstrates that rigor is needed and picture is insufficient.

Comment: Wasn't this proven using the diagonlisation argument ? I think that's pretty visual.

Comment: Plenty of answers so far, but not a single picture...! I don't think there's any good visual answer to this question. Maybe the closest you're going to get is the following: The rationals in the interval $[0,1]$ look like this: "‌ " (too sparse to be visible). And the irrationals look like this: "_". Which obviously doesn't explain anything about *why* it's like that.

Comment: @Vim What is your opinion about proving that there are (uncountably) infinitely many irrational numbers between any two rational numbers through a diagonlisation argument ? And then using the fact that there are only a countably infinite number of rational numbers.

Comment: @user230452 the argument itself is fine of course, but seems unnecessarily complicated. And what's the "visual" point of it?

Comment: @Vim I was asking from the point of view of rigor.

Comment: @user230452 should be fine.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$ is path connected.  That's not really a proof, maybe can't be made in to a proof, but I think it's interesting and relevant.

Comment: @Callus: But coordinates like $(0,\pi)$ also lie in $\Bbb{R^2\setminus Q^2}$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a geometric difference between the rationals and the irrationals: the length of the rationals equals zero, whereas the length of the irrationals equals infinity.

Here's why the rationals have zero length. Start with an enumeration of the rationals: 
$$p_1,p_2,p_3,...
$$

Pick your favorite tiny positive number $\epsilon>0$.

For each $k=1,2,3,...$, let $I_k$ be the interval centered on $p_k$ of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$. Now take the union of these intervals:
$$X = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3 \cup \cdots
$$
The total length of $X$ is no more than the sum 
$$\text{Length}(I_1) + \text{Length}(I_2) + \text{Length}(I_3) + \cdots = \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2^2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2^3} + \cdots = \epsilon
$$
But the rationals are contained in $X$, so the total length of the rationals is at most $\epsilon$.

But you can repeat this argument for tinier and tinier values of $\epsilon$, approaching zero.

So the total length of the rationals is zero.

But the total length of the irrationals is infinity, because it equals the the total length of the whole real line (which is infinity) minus the total length of the rationals (which is zero).

Thus, there are more irrationals than rationals.

Now this argument may sound fishy, but it turns out to be completely rigorous. Once you have developed the Lebesgue measure of the real line, substitute the phrase "Lebesgue measure" for "length", and you've got a proof.

Comment: Although correct, this may raise the question "why can't I do the opposite"? Of course, you can't because the irrationals cannot be enumareted, but that's only if you already know that there are more irrationals than rationals...

Comment: Lebesgue measure isn't really a good measure of cardinals. For instance, the Cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero too, but it has the same cardinal as $\Bbb R$, which has $\infty$ Lebesgue measure. So I'm very suspicious of the rigour of your "proof".

Comment: While I agree with these comments regarding cardinality, I also note that the question does not mention cardinality, whereas it does mention geometry.

Comment: Also, although you do need to know that the rationals are denumerable in order to carry out this proof, you do not need to know that the reals (or the irrationals) are nondenumerable; in fact this proof shows that the irrationals are non denumerable. Cantor's first proof that the reals are non denumerable was also a simple argument with intervals (simpler than the one in my answer), and was discovered by him **before** his diagonalization argument and before he instituted the formal study of cardinality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article

Answer (score 15):

The rationals can be
mapped into the lattice points
$(n, m)$,
which are an infinite set
of isolated points
in the plane.

The irrationals,
by any of the standard ways
of mapping two reals
into one
(such as zipping the digits
of a pair of reals)
fill the whole plane
(with quibbles about two representations
or points missed
being disregarded).

Comment: Could you eventually explain how or what fills the whole plane, I'm missing that part.

Comment: Take the base $b$ representation of a real number, where $b \ge 3$. Make two real numbers from it by taking the base $b$ digits in the even positions for the first ordinate, and the base $b$ digits in the odd positions for the second ordinate. This is similar to the construction that Cantor used to show that the cardinality of points in k-dimensional space is the same as the reals

Comment: To be a bit more concrete, but using the same idea. Think of rational numbers as "the lines of the plane which intersect $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ in a proper extension of $\{(0,0)\}$"; and think of irrational numbers as "the lines of the plane which intersect $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ exactly in $\{ (0,0)\}$". Indeed, this is essentially what it is done in the construction explained in arxiv.org/abs/math/0301015 (for the technicalities one only considers lines through the origin of coordinates and avoids the vertical line)

Comment: In your second example, the most well-known such function maps both the irrationals and the rationals to dense sets in the plane. Just because the rationals also have a discrete injection doesn't imply that the irrationals don't similarly have a discrete injection. Of course we know they can't, but I fail to see how this example elucidates that fact.

Answer (score 9):

If we make a rectangular grid with integer coordinates, it's possible to assign a unique angle to any rational number, using the definition $\tan \phi=y/x$ for $\phi \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

For positive rationals it would look something like this:

[image]

> It's intuitively clear to me that the lines corresponding to the rational numbers can't fill all the space here (the gaps are especially noticeable around the numbers with small denominators / numerators).

This can be considered an illustration to marty cohen's answer.

Comment: Why is it obvious that the lines can't fill all the space? (Without assuming the result we're trying to illustrate.) In particular, the density of the rationals means that, between any two lines (or any line and the axis), you can always fit another line.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I do not consider it proof, only an illustration to marty's answer. There is no pictures in any other answer, so I wanted to add one.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome image!

Comment: @YuriyS I understand that it's supposed to be an illustration, rather than a proof, but I'm taking issue with your claim that something is obvious. Regardless of levels of proof, I don't think it's obvious at all. Also, Marty's answer doesn't use the lines at all: it just points out that the rationals correspond to the grid points and the irrationals to everything else.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I hope my edit seems better to you

Comment: @David With "everything else" you are referring to the space in between?

Comment: @YuriyS Insofar as you're now only saying that it's obvious to you, rather than that it should be obvious to me, I suppose I'm happy. Nonetheless, I'd encourage you to add some explanation of _why_ it's true. It seems to me to be that you're essentially saying, "It's obvious because most reals aren't rationals" but that's exactly the thing you're supposed to be illustrating!

Answer (score 6):

In general, my favorite way to think about this is to think about a countable set (rationals) as the set of all finite strings of $0$'s and $1$'s and an uncountable set (reals) as the set of all infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s.

I think this makes it "geometrically" obvious, at least for me.

**EDIT 1:** Any countable set is in bijection with $\mathbb N$, each element of which has a finite binary representation. Similarly any element of $\mathbb R$ is (by definition of as the completion of $\mathbb Q$) an infinite sequence of rational numbers, where for example you could fix the first $n$ terms of the $n$'th element (ie. $1,10,100,1001,10010,\ldots$).

Although the diagonal argument is at first unappealing, it is in fact geometric in nature, and simpler than it appears. The idea is the following:

Suppose $\mathbb R$ is countable, then the interval $[0,1]$ is also countable (due to the bijection with $\tan^{-1}$) and there is a bijection $\phi:\mathbb N\to\mathbb [0,1]$ (we denote $\phi(n)$ by $\phi_n$, and the $k$'th binary decimal of $\phi_n$ as $\phi_n^k$), and we can list all the elements of $\mathbb R$

$$\label{arr}\tag{1}\phi_1=\phi_1^1\phi_1^2\phi_1^3\ldots\\
\phi_2=\phi_2^1\phi_2^2\phi_2^3\ldots\\
\phi_3=\phi_3^1\phi_3^2\phi_3^3\ldots\\
\vdots$$

now consider the real number $$x=\tilde\phi_1^1\tilde\phi_2^2\tilde\phi_3^3\ldots$$ where $\tilde\phi_i^i=1-\phi_i^i$, then clearly it will follow that
$x\neq \phi_1$, $x\neq \phi_2$, $x\neq \phi_3$, etc... because $x$ always disagrees with $\phi_i$ on the $i$'th decimal, and thus $x\not\in[0,1]$ because if it were, then there would exist some $i$ such that $\phi_i=x$, which we showed impossible. Contradiction.

The "geometric" part of this argument is the fact that you choose $x$ to be the opposite of the diagonal of the array \ref{arr}.

**EDIT 2:** I am not sure thinking of this geometrically is necessary, as it obscures the fact that countability vs uncountability is not really a property of the "geometry" in the real line. In fact I like that Lee Mosher pointed out the intuitive property I am guessing you were looking for (and in your drawing) that the rationals have "measure" zero while irrationals have "measure" one in the interval, but as some people pointed out in the comments, this is not a *characterization* of cardinality. It is true that every countable subset of the real line has "measure" zero, but there are also uncountable sets (1/3-Cantor set) also with "measure" zero.

So here is a nice proof I like that shows that this is really not a geometric property in the sense that you were thinking of, but a property of sets.

Again we take a countable set as all finite binary sequences (which we call $C$), and an uncountable set as the set of all functions $C\to \bf 2$ (where $\bf 2$ denotes the set $\{0,1\}$) which we denote $\bf 2^C$. We see that $\bf 2^C$ is the same as the set of all infinite binary sequences, since the element $\phi\in\bf 2^C$ represents the sequence $\phi_1\phi_2\phi_3\ldots$.

We now show the following lemma (where $B^A$ is the set of all functions $A\to B$):

**Lemma 1:** (Lawvere) *If there exists a surjective function $\Theta:A\to B^A$, then any function $f:B\to B$ has a fixed point.*

Given $f:B\to B$, consider $g:A\to B$ given by $g(a)=f(\Theta(a)(a))$, then since $\Theta$ is surjective there exists $a_f$ such that $\Theta(a_f)=g$, and thus $\Theta(a_f)(a_f)=g(a_f)=f(\Theta(a_f)(a_f))$, so $\Theta(a_f)(a_f)$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Now, suppose there was a bijection $\Theta:C\to\bf 2^C$ (and hence surjection), then the map
$$0\mapsto 1\\1\mapsto 0$$ has a fixed point, which is clearly not the case. Contradiction.

Comment: What, if anything, is geometric about this?

Comment: How would you represent the rationals "as the set of all finite strings of 0's and 1's"?

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I don't quite understand everything, but it looks like you've shown what Vim predicted. I'll wait and see if this question gets some more attention from people that can give a qualified 2 cents on this.

Comment: @marty cohen, My favorite way to map finite binary strings to rationals is using the  Stern-Brocot tree: start at the root and for each 0 or 1, go left or right. When you run out of digits, there's a unique rational. It's a 1-to-1 mapping and as a bonus, trivial to compute.

Answer (score 5):

The rational numbers can be represented diagrammatically as a 'tree' (for example [Farey Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) or [Stern–Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree)). Such a tree, continued infinitely, is a fractal. The outer edge of the fractal will always be rough, whereas the real numbers (if similarly represented) would be smooth.

Comment: What would be the difference between "rough" and "smooth" for a tree of infinite depths? And you *can't* represent the real numbers similarly. Such trees necessarily have a countable number of nodes.

Answer (score 4):

This is a somewhat more "geometric" argument, somewhat analogous to Cantor's.  Consider any sequence of distinct real numbers $x_n$.  I will construct a real number $y$ that is not in the sequence, as the limit of a sequence $y_n$.  Start by choosing $y_1 \ne x_1$.  At stage $n$, we will have a real number $y_n$ that is not $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.  Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ be $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ sorted in increasing order.  For convenience we take $a_0 = -\infty$ and $a_{n+1} = +\infty$.  $x_{n+1}$ will be in one of the $n+1$ open intervals 
 $(a_j, a_{j+1})$.    If we happen to have $x_{n+1} = y_n$, let $y_{n+1}$ be some point of $(x_{n+1}, a_{j+1})$, otherwise $y_{n+1} = y_n$.  In fact I'll take  $$y_{n+1} = \cases{y_n + 10^{-n} & if $a_{j+1} = \infty$\cr
                         y_n + 10^{-n}(a_{j+1}-y_n) & otherwise} $$
It's easy to show that this is a nondecreasing sequence and bounded above, therefore has a limit as $n \to \infty$, and that this limit can't be one of the $x_n$.

Visually, think of $y_n$ as sitting at a point on a number line, with the $x_n$ as (single-point) hailstones coming down from above, and sticking to the number line as they land.  If a hailstone hits $y_n$, it hops a tiny bit to the right, but by such a small distance that it will never get much closer to any of the existing hailstones.